# ACF Checkbox - check box output image

Tags: arrays, wordpress, image, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get the ACF checkbox to output an image when when it is checked. Here is what I have

`<?php if (in_arry('The Home Depot', ("retailers"))) {
echo '<img src="' . echo get_stylesheet dirctory_url() . '/images/thehomedepot.jpg'" alt="The Home Depot">
} elseif(in_arry('True Value', ("retailers"))) {
echo '<img src="' . echo get_stylesheet dirctory_url() . '/images/truevalue.jpg'" alt="The Home Depot">
}`else {

}
?>

retailers is the checkbox field and The Home Depot and True Value are the checkboxes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to get everything working if anyone needs the help.

```
<?php if(in_array('thd', get_field('retailers') ) ) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="';
            echo get_field('the_home_depot_product_url');
            echo '">';
            echo '<img src="../thehomedepot.jpg" alt="The Home Depot" />';
            echo  '<h3>The Home Depot</h3>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $retailers = get_field('retailers'); ?>

<?php if( in_array('The Home Depot', $retailers )): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_dirctory_url(); ?>/images/thehomedepot.jpg" alt="The Home Depot">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure that 'The Home Depot' is the value of the checkbox though, not just the label. Output the array with print_r($retailers); so you can see what you're working with.

Comment: here is what I get when i print out the retailers Array ([0] => The Home Depot )  When I add the code above it will not show the image for some reason any ideas?

Comment: I just noticed, in copying part of your code, there was an underscore missing in get_stylesheet_directory_url() - was that the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on I added the code which looks right to me but it is not showing the image or even the div.

Comment: Perhaps try setting up so field value as 'the-home-depot' instead?